# Laravel's uuid type

Tags: laravel

I was reading Laravel's documentation that I noticed Laravel 7 offers a uuid type in the page for [database migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations)

Unfortunately I couldn't find much information about using it in the documentation. How is such a column filled when I insert a new record? Does Laravel fill it on its own? Does Laravel guarantee it to be unique or should I worry about collisions? Can I use this field to create short links for the posts of a blog, for example?

Comment: @STA Thanks. Does Laravel also guarantee it to be unique? Or should I make sure its unique on my own?

Comment: @STA I just checked in tinker and it says that 'short_link' (the name of my uuid column) does not have a default value.

Comment: You can check this https://github.com/webpatser/laravel-uuid

Comment: A good UUID generator will create a UUID which will be globally unique with extremely high probability so you don't really need to check if it's unique, though you could if you wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel should fill this on its own by setting the `keyType`(untested) on your model:

```
protected $keyType = 'string';
```

The key, whether you fill it manually or not, is unique as laravel depends on [Ramsey](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/composer.json#L32).

To manually acquire a uuid you may use the provided [helper](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-str-uuid):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return (string) Str::uuid();
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to force it to be unique? I mean I can define my column to accept unique values only, but then I should run a loop until no match is found. Is there a built-in way to take care of this?

Comment: I added protected $keyType = 'string' to my model but tinker still says that 'short_link' (my uuid column) doesn't have a default value. Did I have to replace $keyType or 'string' with something?

Comment: Add a unique constraint to your column with a default value of a GUID.